# ReactJS and Symfony2 How to detect either user logged in or not inside React component

Tags: symfony, reactjs

Could you please share your experience and best practices when it comes to
ReactJS and Symfony2 used in common?  **How do you usually detect either user logged in or not inside React component ?** Lets assume we need to show a "Delete" button or say hello to user in case he/she is logged in. What is your suggestions ? Store user's credential in global scope ?

```
const ExampleBox = React.createClass({

    maybeSayHi: function () {   
        if (USER.IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY) {
            return <div>Hi, user</div>;
        }
    },


    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.maybeSayHi()}
                <div>
                    Lorem
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Imho, react is all about pushing data into components so I push a user object.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussions I used following solution.

- Inside my TWIG template I define few hidden element where I set all needed user's credentials such as user id and locale (language):

```js
<input type="hidden" id="user_language" value="{{ app.request.getLocale() }}"/>
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}
    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="{{ app.user.id }}" />
{% endif %}
```

- Then during React`s component initialization I grab values from these hidden fields into components as [props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html).

```js
var userId = document.getElementById("user_id").value;
var userLanguage = document.getElementById("user_language").value;

//We even can store it in the global variable
window.USER_DETAILS = {
    user_id: userId,
    user_language: userLanguage
};

ReactDOM.render(<Application user_id={userId} user_language={userLanguage } />, document.getElementById('application'));
```